# Having problem to obtain data when sending curl request from terminal to Twitter API

Tags: curl, twitter, twitter-api-v2

I am trying to make twitter API request from MAC Terminal using curl. I already made developer account, and obtained all keys and tokens.

In documentation they provided code to make request. This is the code:

```
curl --request GET 'https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent?query=from:twitterdev' --header 'Authorization: Bearer $BEARER_TOKEN'
```

Instruction is to substitute `$BEARER_TOKEN` with actual Token, which I did. However I get back this :

> {"client_id":"27180208","detail":"When authenticating requests to the
> Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter
> developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project
> via the developer
> portal.","registration_url":"https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/projects/overview","title":"Client
> Forbidden","required_enrollment":"Appropriate Level of API
> Access","reason":"client-not-enrolled","type":"https://api.twitter.com/2/problems/client-forbidden"}%

What is the solution and why is it not letting me to obtain data?